VSCode Window Border Line Removal
With gray border:

With no border:

I'm trying to remove the gray border from my Visual Studio Code window, but I'm struggling to do so. I've tried using an extension, but it removes not only the border but also the border radius. Is there any advice or method someone can share to help me remove just the gray border while retaining the border radius and window box shadow?

To retain the border radius and window box shadow while removing the gray border in Visual Studio Code, you will have to do customization, potentially using CSS injections via the settings.json file or through a custom theme extension.

You can try this (although I am not sure how well it works on Windows..).  In your settings.json:
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "window.activeBorder": "#fff0"
  }

The fourth hex color code is for opacity - that the above would set it to 0 opacity.
